# Warning: Multiple EventSystem in scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity I have two `Canvas`. In every `Canvas` has own **EventSytems**.But when I RUN this it gives me yellow message

> Multiple EventSystems in scene... this is not supported

..and I tried inactive one of the canvas by script.After Warning not appeared But then buttons not working. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple Canvas in unity is fine, i already try that.
But multiple EventSystem is not allowed, you have to remove on of the EventSystem GameObject/Component.

One EventSystem is okay for multiple canvas.

Also it's better to place your event system object outside the Canvas, don't make it as the child of the canvas.

Comment: I tried to move outside the canvas but then buttons not working

Comment: Destroy all EventSystem in your scene.

Then go To Menu > GameObject > UI > EventSystem, try if that working

Comment: Technically using more than one canvas is allowed (they are just gameobjects with certain components after all) However it is not reccomended to use more than one and in most cases there really isn't a reason to have more than one.

You can technically use multiple canvasses with a single EventSystem attached to one of them, but it is recommended to stick with one Canvas.

Comment: What LAKster said is BLATANTLY false. Unity specifically discusses using multiple canvases as dirtying a canvas is an expensive operation. You are very specifically better off with many canvases each dealing with its own UI.

Answer (score -3):

Only one Canvas is supported in a scene. This error shows you that having two doesn't work.

There is no reason to have more than one canvas at that.

EDIT: Technically using more than one canvas with only one of them having an EventSystem is possible, however it is not reccomended seeing as it can lead to problems down the line.

Comment: This is completely false. Unity specifically recommends that you use multiple canvases, separated by functionality, because dirtying a canvas, i.e. changing the RectTransform on a canvas object is an expensive operation requiring redraw of all UI objects on the canvas. This comment should be downvoted forever.

Answer (score -3):

Only one Canvas is supported per scene.

If you want multiple Canvas (which there is a legitimate argument for), then **add a Graphic raycaster** to your new canvas. The event system should pick up Button events inside now.